# CakePHP 3 - Get Form Input Field Name in Array - Use Hash?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

OK, I've got a simple form submitted to my controller.

In my controller:

```
$thedata = $this->request->data;
debug($thedata);
```

Results in:

```
[
'number' => '102',
'color' => 'blue',
'size' => 'large'
]
```

I want to extract from this result an array that is the input field names.  The result should be

```
$thearray = ['number','color','size'];
```

What is the best way to do this in CakePHP? I'm using using 3.5.2.

Will Hash::extract do this?  If so, how would that work?

Thanks in advance for any advice.
D.

Comment: **[http://php.net/array_keys](http://php.net/array_keys)**

Comment: YEP!  That does it.  $thearray = array_keys($thedata);  I thought perhaps there was a CakePHP way, but I guess the basic PHP way does it.  Thank you ndm.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my issue:

```
$thearray = array_keys($thedata);
```